# VBA manual transpose

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

So I have noticed that Application.transpose doesnt take more than 255 characters and my array contain more than 300 characters or so. Is there a manual or another way to transpose an array? Currently I use

```
Function Transpose(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arrIn(r)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    Transpose = arrOut

End Function
```

But I have noticed that this only takes a 1D array and transposes it, but I must be able to go from 1D to 2D and vise verse. Anyone who knows how to do this in a efficient way?

Updated: This is what I currently use, but I think it needs some improvements.

```
Function Transpose1(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i) = arrIn(r, UBound(arrIn, 2))
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    Transpose1 = arrOut

End Function


' From one 2 two
Function Transpose2(arrIn) As String()
    Dim arrOut() As String, r As Long, ln As Long, i As Long

    ln = (UBound(arrIn) - LBound(arrIn)) + 1
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ln, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    For r = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arrIn(r)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    Transpose2 = arrOut

End Function
```

Comment: Application.transpose also has an iteration limit of 32768.

Comment: what about using a range in a hidden sheet with copy and paste special/transpose ?

Comment: Can you have two different functions? One for 1D to 2D and other for 2D to 1D?

Comment: @ Sorry for late answer, i dont want to evolve more sheet as this may be "unknown" if the user changes workbook or something else.

Comment: @Aneta That is what I have come up with so far but I do not like the solution. Can update the text above with what I have and hopefully someone can help me make it more efficient.

Comment: @Fredrik Perfect, now you just have to find out how many dimensions has your array...
`on error resume next
if UBound(arrIn, 2)=1 then 
on error goto 0
call Transpose1(arrIn)
else
on error goto 0
call Transpose2(arrIn)
end if`