# Excel VBA Manual Transpose

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works until used on a directory with paths over 255 characters.
Runtime error 13 mismatch occurs.
I have a hunch that the built in .transpose operation does not support 255 characters.
How can I manually do this operation?

My other crawler is not recursive, so I have never had this issue.
At this point I'm wondering if recursive efficiency is worth it.
Also the UNC path output is a requirement, shortening it to drive letter is a not an option.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateFileStructureReport()

Dim Msheet As String
Dim minNum As Integer
Msheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Call GetFileList
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Range("A2").Select

End Sub


  Sub GetFileList()
    Dim ans As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim myResults As Variant
    Dim lCount As Long

    ans = Application.CommandBars("Web").Controls("Address:").Text
    If ans = "" Then Exit Sub
    ans = Left(ans, InStrRev(ans, "\"))

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ans)

    'the variable dimension has to be the second one
    ReDim myResults(0 To 6, 0 To 0)

    ' place make some headers in the array

    myResults(0, 0) = "Extension"
    myResults(1, 0) = "Bytes"
    myResults(2, 0) = "Created"
    myResults(3, 0) = "Modified Info"
    myResults(4, 0) = "Last Accessed"
    myResults(5, 0) = "File Name"
    myResults(6, 0) = "\\Root\T01\T02\T03\T04\T05\T06\T07\T08\T09\T10\T11\T12\T13\T14\T15\T16\T17\T18\T19\T20"

    'Send the folder to the recursive function
    FillFileList objFolder, myResults, lCount

    ' Dump these to a worksheet
    DumpToWorksheet myResults

    'tidy up
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    End Sub

Private Sub FillFileList(objFolder As Object, ByRef myResults As Variant, ByRef lCount As Long, Optional strFilter As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    Dim fsoSubFolders As Object

    'load the array with all the files
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        lCount = lCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve myResults(0 To 6, 0 To lCount)

        myResults(0, lCount) = objFile.Type
        myResults(1, lCount) = objFile.Size
        myResults(2, lCount) = objFile.DateCreated
        myResults(3, lCount) = objFile.DateLastModified
        myResults(4, lCount) = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        myResults(5, lCount) = objFile.Name
        myResults(6, lCount) = objFile.Path

    Next objFile

    'recursively call this function with any subfolders

    Set fsoSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    DoEvents
    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoSubFolders
        FillFileList fsoSubFolder, myResults, lCount
    Next fsoSubFolder

End Sub

Private Sub DumpToWorksheet(varData As Variant, Optional mySh As Worksheet)

    Dim iSheetsInNew As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim myColumnHeaders() As String
    Dim l As Long, NoOfRows As Long

    If mySh Is Nothing Then
        'make a workbook if we didn't get a worksheet
        iSheetsInNew = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iSheetsInNew
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)
    Else
        Set mySh = sh
    End If

    'since we switched the array dimensions, have to transpose
    With sh
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(varData, 2) + 1, UBound(varData, 1) + 1)) = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174829/vba-manual-transpose/51181924#51181924

Comment: type mismatch on your transpose line, correct?

Comment: You can manually transpose by creating an appropriately sized and dimenstioned array, and looping to "manually" copy.  BUT, neither Excel nor the Windows API can handle longer path names.  Excel is limited to about 216 characters; and the Windows API to 260 characters. So be certain about which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Yes dwirony, it occurs at the end inside "with sh" statement.